# Adding workstation nodes in HPC Pack 2016

Tags: azure, cluster-computing, hpc

I am using Microsoft HPC Pack 2016 update 2 on a local network and on-premise cluster. We have employed [topology 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/high-performance-computing/appendix-1-cluster-network-topologies-for-workstation-nodes?view=hpc16-ps) (all nodes on the enterprise network). Head node is successfully setup and running. The problem is that after manual installation of HPC Pack 2016 update 2 on different Windows 10 workstations which are all on the same local network, some cannot be found and added to the cluster using the HPC Cluster Manager. I can’t see them on the HPC Cluster Manager running on the head node, neither through “resource management > nodes”, nor using the wizard to add node. While the same steps to install and add node work for some of the workstations, it does not work on some others. Is there any way to track down to find the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was due to trust relationship. This can be verified using nltest /trusted_domains command. Resetting the trust relationship fixed the problem.